# Is it possible to replace this radar gun handle wiring with a battery?

Tags: batteries, circuit-analysis, dc

I have a radar gun and the detachable handle needs to be directly plugged into a car cigarette outlet in order to work. This is quite troublesome as I always need an outlet and a cigarette socket to wall outlet converter for it to work. Today I measured some voltages and took apart the handle.

[image]

The voltage I measured at the end of the handle was 7.6 Volts (where the red arrow is). The input to the handle is a standard 12 VDC. Looking at the manual for the radar gun, it appears peak operating needs are 7.6 Volts and 0.66 amps. I am wondering if anyone would know what is going on within the handle itself. If I took out everything, could I in theory replace all the wiring with a battery and solder it onto where the red arrow points to?

For reference, the entire radar gun and handle looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes.

The circuit inside the handle would be a buck converter.

Going by the available information on the Stalker Radar Gun and its accessories, 2 battery configurations appear feasible:

1. Six 1.2V 2500mAh rechargeable NiMH batteries in series
2. Two 3.6V 2500mAh rechargeable Li-ion batteries in series.

They would be capable of 2 hours of continuous transmitting after a full recharge.

Comment: Do I need to worry about Continuous Discharge Ratings? In one battery I found I saw it was 20Amps. Is that too high?

Comment: What a battery is capable of does not matter. The actual discharge is dependent on the load.

Comment: I have a portable car jump starter with one of those low resistance batteries that has 12V output, but claims to be able to dump up to 1200 Amps (here: https://www.amazon.com/GOOLOO-18000mAh-SuperSafe-Starter-Portable/dp/B0748D8KT6). If I connected the clamps, will this also only discharge what is needed? Is there a chance it might dump it all and be dangerous? Sorry if this sounds stupid, I am new to electronics. Thank you

Comment: Yes, the current is dependent on the load. The danger is real should you short-circuit the battery terminals. That problem is taken care of by using a fuse. A 2A fuse would suffice for your application.

Comment: It would be more convenient for you if you could lay your hands on a battery handle to hold rechargeable cells and a companion charger. https://www.stalkerradar.com/sportsradar/Accessories-Pro.html

Answer (score 1):

A good place to start would be to determine what kind of circuit the handle uses. Is it is possible you can find the name of the IC, and then determine its function in the datasheet. The circuit overall looks a bit like a buck converter. If that's the case you should be able to replace it with a battery. All though I might be mistaken. Which is why I would recommend looking up the function of the IC.